# how to require classes in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I was writing a project with Nodejs, and I using the ES6. I wrote a class named `Products` in `Products.js` file :

```
class Products
{
...
}
```

For import this class to another file (like `index.js`), I use `requre('Products.js');` and this error displayed :

> Error: Cannot find module 'Products.js'

How to I require this class in index.js?

Comment: `export default class HelloWorld{}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to include the path in the require like this :

`var productFile = require("./Products")`

consider the `.`(dot) in the require statement

Also you need to export the Products Module like 
`module.exports = Products`